# How to rename an agent pool in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

How to rename an existing agent pool in Team Foundation Server 2017?

I've created an agent pool in TFS 2017. Now I want to rename it for a better understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We cannot rename the existing agent pool in TFS, you can delete the existing agent pool, then create a new pool with the name for a better understanding, then reconfigure the agents with the new pool.

On the Settings->Agent Pools, for each Pool Name on its right there is a small black triangle pointing down, left click on it, a context menu will appear, last menu item is '**Delete**', click on that the Agent Pool will be gone after a confirmation dialog.

[Deploy an agent on Windows](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the name of the pool if you resort to using the rest API, at least for later Azure releases.
Microsoft description found here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/update?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0